# HTTP.Receive() always null

Tags: http, null

```
{
        http.Connect();
        http.Request();
        String raw_data = http.Receive();
        http.Close();`enter code here`
        if (raw_data == null) return RETURN_ERROR;
        data = raw_data;
        return RETURN_SUCCESS;
```

}

Hello Guys, i got the same Program on my Laptop and my Computer, both in the same Network.

Laptop: Windows 8.1, VS Prof.
Computer: Windows 7, VS Ult.

On the Laptop it always works, but on my Computer it always returns null ( this isn't the full code )
Any Ideas why it doesnt work on my Computer?

Comment: Could you provide a live example?

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the Problem. Since all the links are http and not https it doesnt work with YouTube, youtube only works with https, or google only accepts this one.